# Android studio 1.2.2 Frequently restarted

Tags: android-studio, windows-7

Facing a problem with Android Studio 1.2.2 . It's getting restarted frequently after opening an existing project. Is there anyone else who faced this type of problem before?

I had started a Google Map API project and after that the problem started. Even deleting that project could not solve this .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have not seen the problem (although I've admittedly not used the map api much in 1.2.2) Same problem with 1.3?

Comment: I do not try 1.3.0 yet. So I have no idea about that.